# Silence is gold!

Tags: vocabulary

If we want to say that : Keeping silence is much better than speaking i.e. by speaking one may happen to make a mistake but by keeping silence he will not make any mistake or he will be safe from mistakes that are called slip of tongue... is there a proverb in English for such situation? Is there any proverb about importance of 'silence'?
Silence is gold! Is this a standard proverb?

Answer (score 1):

It is *silence is golden*, and that is a short version of saying [*speech is silver, silence is golden*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speech_is_silver,_silence_is_golden).

[phrases.org.uk](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/silence-is-golden.html) describes it as

> A proverbial saying, often used in circumstances where it is thought that saying nothing is preferable to speaking.

... and states *the origin of this phrase is obscured by the mists of time*. Further reading over there.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/silence_is_golden) gives as definitions:

> 1. Peace and quiet have great value.
> 2. Often the best choice is to say nothing

BTW. Try [The Tremeloes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n03g8nsaBro)